# startActivityForResult to an activity that only displays a progressdialog

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm trying to make an activity that is asked for some result. This result is normally returned instantly (in the onCreate), however, sometimes it is nesesary to wait for some internet-content to download which causes the "loader"-activity to show. What I want is that the loader-activity don't display anything more than a progressdialog (and that you can still se the old activity calling the loader-activity in the background) and I'm wondering wheather or not this is possible.

The code I'm using as of now is:

```
//ListComicsActivity.java
public class ListComicsActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final int REQUEST_COMICS = 1;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_comics);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intents.ACTION_GET_COMICS);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_COMICS);
            }
        });
    }

    /** Called when an activity called by using startActivityForResult finishes. */
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "The activity finnished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}


//LoaderActivity.java (answers to Intents.ACTION_GET_COMICS action-filter)
public class LoaderActivity extends Activity
{
    private Intent result = null;
    private ProgressDialog pg = null;
    private Runnable returner = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if(pg != null)
                pg.dismiss();
            LoaderActivity.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
            LoaderActivity.this.finish();
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        String action = getIntent().getAction();
        if(action.equals(Intents.ACTION_GET_COMICS))
        {
            Runnable loader = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    WebProvider.DownloadComicList();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setDataAndType(ComicContentProvider.COMIC_URI, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.mymir.comic");
                    returnResult(intent);
                }
            };
            pg = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Downloading", "Please wait, retrieving data....");
            Thread thread = new Thread(null, loader, "LoadComicList");
            thread.start();
        }
        else
        {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void returnResult(Intent intent)
    {
        result = intent;
        runOnUiThread(returner);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of the loader activity, if you don't want to show it, why not just take the runnable to an outside class and launch it in your calling activity's click event?

Comment: The point is that I can have different loaders. And also, you could install more loaders later at a different application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can do this by setting the activitys `theme`-attribute to `@android:style/Theme.Dialog` and calling `this.setVisible(false);` in the `onCreate`-method of the activity.